# jQuery events not firing in AngularJS application

Tags: jquery, angularjs

Please don't tell me why I shouldn't be using jQuery in AngularJS. Been using jQuery for years, however somewhat new to AngularJS, so I'm perplexed on this situation.

I have multiple controllers. In one controller I have a `$(function()` that has some `on` events, and those work perfectly. However, in this new controller my events aren't firing, at all. I implemented `hoverIntent` plugin, which I use frequently (not shown for brevity, and **it's commented out** at the moment).

```
<div id="testing"><a id="abcsyz" style="border: 1px solid red; height: 50px; display:block;" href="/somewhere">Testing</a></div>
<input type="text" name="searchAffGroupVal" ng-model="searchAffGroupVal" placeholder="Search Records..." ng-required="true" />
```

**In Controller**

```
    $(function () {
        console.log('fired')

        $('#testing').mouseover(function () {
            console.log('mouse')
        })

        $('input[name="searchAffGroupVal"]').on('keyup', function () {
            console.log('keyup')
        })

        console.log('fired')
    })
```

[image]

As you can see, both "fired" are coming up in console, however a simple `mouseover` and `keyup` are not working at all. I have checked just in case to see if there are any more elements in the project w/ an `id` of `testing`, and there's not. No console errors, **and other angular methods are firing OK in the controller as well**, so I know it's working, just not the jQuery.

Comment: Is the HTML being dynamically included? `ng-if` or `ng-include`? - Give a quick try with `$(document).on("mouseover", "#testing", function() {` and see if that works

Comment: jQuery is out of angular world and no watchers are bind to them , hence its doesn't triggers the data binding or any of angular sort , you have to explicitly call $scope.$digest or $apply . in my opinion you can use jqlite of angulars which is a subset of angular

Comment: @shushanthp That still doesn't explain why my other jQuery in another controller is working though. I know that jQLite is already inside angular.js file, but I chose not to use that and wanted the full library. In the other controller I didn't have to use `$scope.$digest` or `$apply`, and I have `on` events for elements in there

Comment: Is it not possible that your elements dont exist at the time of binding the events? If so, you may need to bind events after the DOM elements exist.

Comment: @RobScott in you another jQuery there is somewhere watchers , it may ng-if or ng-click or someother angular directives which kicking off the digest cycle

Comment: @Wancieho I literally commented everything else out on the page w/ the exception of those 2 elements to see if there were other functions firing and taking hold of the jQuery events. The page is, however, inside an `ng-view`

Comment: @RobScott -- Can you try an actual event delegated selector? `$('input[name="searchAffGroupVal"]').on('keyup', function () {` is not the correct use of `.on` - try the example I gave in the top comment. The page is in an `ngView` - it's definitely not binding your events because they don't exist at the time the script is run.

Comment: @tymeJV Yes I just looked up some posts on ngView. Perhaps implenting a directive instead would help? I tried to add `angular.element(document).ready(function() {}` but that didn't work either - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32900475/jquery-or-jqlite-not-working-with-elements-inside-ng-view-ng-view

Answer (score -1):

There are directives for angular js for both functions.

ng-mouseover -> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseover

ng-keyup -> https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup

```
<div id="testing" ng-mouseover="foo()"><a id="abcsyz" style="border: 1px solid red; height: 50px; display:block;" href="/somewhere">Testing</a></div><input ng-keyup="bar()" type="text" name="searchAffGroupVal" ng-model="searchAffGroupVal" placeholder="Search Records..." ng-required="true" />
```

In your controller you set e.g.

```
$scope.foo = function() {
   console.log('fired foo');
}

$scope.bar = function() {
   console.log('fired bar');
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't need directives for those events, they were just placeholders to determine why other events weren't firing

Comment: [https://jsfiddle.net/6b3ntn73/14/](https://jsfiddle.net/6b3ntn73/14/) , here it works.